# Sqoop export job failed

Tags: oracle, hive, hdfs, sqoop, cloudera

Can't export HDFS contents to oracle DB.

**Oracle:**

```
    create table DB1.T1 (
        id1 number,
        id2 number
    );
```

**Hive:**

```
    create table DB1.T1 (
        id1 int,
        id2 int
    );
    insert into table values(0,0);
```

**Sqoop:**

```
$ sqoop export \
--connect driver:@ip:port:DB \
--username=DB --password  'bad_practice_pwd' \
-m 1 \
--export-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/DB1.db/T1/file" \
--table DB1.T1
--direct
```

**Error:**

> 18/04/16 17:11:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1520336080249_0240 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1520336080249_0240_m_000000
>   Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
>
> 18/04/16 17:11:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
>           Job Counters
>                   Failed map tasks=1
>                   Launched map tasks=1
>                   Rack-local map tasks=1
>                   Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4872
>                   Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
>                   Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4872
>                   Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4872
>                   Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4988928 18/04/16 17:11:00 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group
>   FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead 18/04/16
>   17:11:00 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 16.9653
>   seconds (0 bytes/sec) 18/04/16 17:11:00 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead 18/04/16 17:11:00 INFO
>   mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records. 18/04/16 17:11:00 ERROR
>   tool.ExportTool: Error during export: Export job failed!
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:439)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.exportTable(OracleManager.java:465)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have defined the Hive table as:

```
    create table DB1.T1 (
    id1 int,
    id2 int
    )
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n;
```

And the export was thence accomplished.

> 18/04/18 13:09:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
>           File System Counters
>                   FILE: Number of bytes read=0
>                   FILE: Number of bytes written=175430
>                   FILE: Number of read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of large read operations=0
>                   FILE: Number of write operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes read=189
>                   HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
>                   HDFS: Number of read operations=4
>                   HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>                   HDFS: Number of write operations=0
>           Job Counters
>                   Launched map tasks=1
>                   Rack-local map tasks=1
>                   Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=2747
>                   Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
>                   Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=2747
>                   Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=2747
>                   Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=2812928
>           Map-Reduce Framework
>                   Map input records=1
>                   Map output records=1
>                   Input split bytes=182
>                   Spilled Records=0
>                   Failed Shuffles=0
>                   Merged Map outputs=0
>                   GC time elapsed (ms)=47
>                   CPU time spent (ms)=1620
>                   Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=359587840
>                   Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2823344128
>                   Total committed heap usage (bytes)=619184128
>           File Input Format Counters
>                   Bytes Read=0
>           File Output Format Counters
>                   Bytes Written=0
>   18/04/18 13:09:11 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 189 bytes in 13.8196 seconds (13.6762 bytes/sec)
>   18/04/18 13:09:11 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 1 records.

Comment: Thank You so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, When I narrowed down the location where hive stores file, I found that the null values were converted into '\n' however the target MySQL columns were expecting int values, I had to remove those values from tables, and then issue gets resolved.